# Delphi TestInsight cant load the DLL

Tags: delphi, dunitx

I'm trying to install and use TestInsight in Delphi XE 10.4 downloaded from https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/testinsight/wiki/Home and selecting the link http://files.dsharp.org/TestInsight/1.1.9.0/TestInsightSetup.zip

I close Delphi and run the setup and it completes ok.

When I try to start Delphi, I now get the following error

[image]

This looks like it doesnt really match the 10.4 Enterprise version as the installed DLL is the one it finds, but it seems to be missing one of the exports.

I have applied the current patches to 10.4

Is there a newer version that resolves this ?

Comment: Why is this tagged dunitx? Shouldn't you create an issue at the TestInsight repo?

Comment: Fair call. The create issue button wasn't visible for me. It was on DSharp, but not for TestInsight. I added a /new to the end (thats what the DSHarp one had) and it seems I needed to agree to some atlasian terms. After that the create button appeared. I'll close this and open a new ticket on the TestInsight site.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins compiled with 10.4.1 are not compatible with 10.4.0 and vice versa (Embarcaderos fault, not mine).

I always build my plugins with the newest release thus you need to update to 10.4.1 or use an older binary which I had attached on https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/testinsight/issues/134

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been moved to the TestInsight issue board at  https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/testinsight/issues/142/delphi-testinsight-cant-load-the-dll